# How to get single object of javascript array in console.log

Tags: javascript

This JS array outputs with console.log(response)

```js
{
  px_hide_header: "0"
  px_hide_header_progressbar: "0"
  px_hide_menu: "0"
  px_hide_popup: "0"
  px_overlay_menu: "0"
  px_page_slug: "loremfa-ipsum"
  px_page_thumbnail: "618"
  px_page_thumbnail_src: "https://website.local/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/image.jpg"
  __proto__: Object
```

How can I get the value of "px_page_slug":

1. In the console?
2. In a var?

The code below is not working.

```
console.log(response.px_page_slug);
```

Comment: More info needed. How is `response` loaded? Are you sure it's an object? Have you checked the console? Etc.

Comment: here it is working, once `response` is that object

Comment: what does `console.log(response)` outputs?

Comment: console.log(response) outputs the first code, I updated the original post

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49452809/574531) from the OP, the actual problem was that `response` was a JSON string; however, this is not accurately reflected in the question.

Answer (score -2):

This is an object not an array. To get the the value of a single property, use this format

```
console.log(objectName.propertyName);
```

or

```
console.log(objectName["propertyName"]);
```

Answer (score -2):

The **solution** was to redeclare "response" in a var and I applied the solution of mLrv like this:

```
test = JSON.parse( response );
console.log(test.px_page_slug);
```

Without this the output was "undefined" in the console.
*Thank you for the answers, these helped me out!*

Comment: What you're doing there is parsing a JSON string into a JavaScript object and assigning it to a variable. "Redeclaring" is not the correct term. Your original problem was that you were trying to access the property `px_page_slug` on a string, which gives you `undefined` because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Herohtar which is weird since the console showed an object and not a string